# FASM x86 msg db new line

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I was wondering something. I continued learning some assembly, and I started to understand more of it. Anyways, let's carry on. This is what I've made:

```
org 100h
; Message 1
mov ah,09
mov dx,msg
int 21h
; Message 2
; LOL
mov ah,09
mov dx,msg2
int 21h
mov ah,08
int 21h
; ENd
int 20h
msg db "hello world!$", 0Dh, 0Ah, 0
msg2 db "made by Josh!$", 0Dh, 0Ah, 0
```

However, between msg and msg2, there's no new line. It means, both 'hello world!' and 'made by Josh!' are on the same line. How can I add a new line?

Also, if somebody wants to comment on the code itself, please do it. I am a starter on Assembly and I really want to learn it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the interrupt you are using -- "AH = 09h - WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT" -- the character code `$` is the End of String marker, not the binary `0` as you seem to think.

Put the `$` at the very end to solve it:

```
msg db "hello world!", 0Dh, 0Ah, "$"
```

There is no need for the `0` byte here, so better leave it out for clarity.

Is this all your code? It seems you are missing an End of Program interrupt:

```
mov ah, 4Ch
mov al, 0
int 21h
```

(AH = 4Ch - "EXIT" - TERMINATE WITH RETURN CODE)

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that. I'm still learning assembly, so I might be doing things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a new line very much the same way like you do with printing the string and use it repeatedly.

```
org 100h
mov dx,msg
mov ah,9h
int 21h

mov dx,newline ;put newline in between
mov ah,9h
int 21h

mov dx,msg2
mov ah,9h
int 21h

;int 20h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h 

msg db 'Hello World$'
msg2 db 'Hello FASM$'
newline db 0dh,0ah,'$'
```